# What is the limit $ \displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}\bigg[x^2(\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{x}}-\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{x+1}})\bigg] $?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How do I solve this limit?
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[x^2(\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{x}}-\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{x+1}})\right] $$

Can you try to do it without Taylor expansion or l'Hopital would be wonderful.

Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 2):

$x^2(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-e^{\frac{1}{x+1}})=x^2e^{\frac{1}{x}}(1-e^{\frac{-1}{x(x+1)}})\sim x^2e^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{1}{x(x+1)}\sim e^{\frac{1}{x}}\to_{x \to \infty}1$

Comment: why E=1-e^(-1/x(x+1)) is 1/x(x+1)?

Comment: Ohhh I understood. You can write that expresion E/(-1/x(x+1)) (=1) * (-1/x(x+1)) which is -1/x(x+1) and you have a "-" in front of it so it is 1/x(x+1) right?

Comment: you have $e^x-1\sim x$ so $1-e^x \sim -x$ and $1-e^{\frac{-1}{x(x+1)}}\sim -(\frac{-1}{x(x+1)})) = \frac{1}{x(x+1)}$

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2\int_{\frac{1}{x+1}}^{\frac{1}{x}}e^t\,dt = \frac{x^2}{x(x+1)}+O\left(x^2 \int_{\frac{1}{x+1}}^{\frac{1}{x}}t\,dt\right) = \color{red}{\large 1}+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) $$
as $x\to +\infty$.

Comment: I am interested in your development can you explain ? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @OvyOvy: The limit is one by the dominated convergence theorem, as shown above. Are you confident with the Landau notation $O(\cdot)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure if you're allowed to use the mean value theorem, but anyway, I'll write it down and wish it to be useful.

Let's define function $f$ over $(0,\infty)$ as $$f(x)=\mathrm{e}^{\frac1x}$$ Since $f$ is differentiable over its domain, according to the mean value theorem, for every $a, b \in (0,\infty)$ and $a\le b$, there exists $c\in [a,b]$ where $$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

Now, by substituting $a$ and $b$ with $x$ and $x+1$, respectively, and inserting the derivative of $f$, we'll get $$-\frac{1}{c^2}\mathrm{e}^{\frac1c}=\mathrm{e}^{\frac1{x+1}}-\mathrm{e}^{\frac1{x}},\quad c\in[x,x+1]$$ and note that since $c$ is dependent to $x$, one can rewrite the above equation as $$-\frac{1}{c^2(x)}\mathrm{e}^{\frac1{c(x)}}=\mathrm{e}^{\frac1{x+1}}-\mathrm{e}^{\frac1x},\quad c(x)\in[x,x+1]$$

Multiplying both sides by $-x^2$ results in $$\frac{x^2}{c^2(x)}\mathrm{e}^{\frac1{c(x)}}=x^2\left(\mathrm{e}^{\frac1x}-\mathrm{e}^{\frac1{x+1}}\right),\quad c(x)\in[x,x+1]$$

Now, the original limit in question, $L$, would be

\begin{aligned}L&=\lim_{x\to\infty}{x^2\left(\mathrm{e}^{\frac1x}-\mathrm{e}^{\frac1{x+1}}\right)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{x^2}{c^2(x)}\mathrm{e}^{\frac1{c(x)}}},\quad c(x)\in[x,x+1]
\end{aligned}

The above limit can be splitted into two limits, i.e.,
$$L=\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{x^2}{c^2(x)}}\lim_{x\to\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{\frac1{c(x)}}},\quad c(x)\in[x,x+1]$$

Both of the above limits are equal to unity. For the first limit, since $x\le c(x) \le x+1$, then $$\frac{x^2}{(x+1)^2} \le \frac{x^2}{c^2(x)}\le \frac{x^2}{x^2}=1$$ which by using the squeeze theorem results in $$L_1=\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{x^2}{c^2(x)}}=1$$ You can use a similar argument for the second limit and thus $$L_2=\lim_{x\to\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{\frac1{c(x)}}}=1$$
Finally $L$ will be found $$L=L_1L_2=1$$